# Meta-analysis - effect size from multiple severity groups

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am currently performing a meta analysis to evaluate whether a measure (let's call it Meas) is correlated to the severity of a disease (Sev).
The severity of the disease is reported as a score from 0 to 10.
Most studies would report the pearson coefficient between Meas and Sev.

However, some others compute means and sds of Meas for different severity groups.
For these latter, I want to compute an effect size to convert to Cohen's d and then report it as a Person coefficient (following chapter 7 from Introduction to meta-analysis by Borenstein).

Thus, I have the following question:
Let's say a study has 3 severity groups:

$$
\begin{array}{lllll}
       & Sev␣mean & Meas␣mean & Meas␣SD & nb␣in␣group \\
group1 & 3        & 1         & 0.1     & 20          \\
group2 & 5.5      & 2         & 0.2     & 30          \\
group3 & 7        & 4         & 0.1     & 30         
\end{array}
$$

How can I compute an effect size to combine the evolution on Meas accross the 3 groups?

I think of 2 things:
 - I compute a Pearson correlation coefficient between the means of the severity groups () and the means of the measures of the severity groups:

$$ Pearson (\begin{bmatrix} mean␣Sev␣group1 & mean␣Meas␣group 1\\mean␣Sev␣group2 & mean␣Meas␣group 2\\mean␣Sev␣group3 & mean␣Meas␣group3\end{bmatrix})
$$
 - I compute the standardised mean difference between group2 and group1 and then between group3 and group2. Then I take the mean of the two as the effect size.

Does one of them make sense? If not, any other idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It isn't clear to me how the three groups in your example are constructed. Based on two cutoff values for the severity variable? In any case, you probably want to compute a polyserial correlation coefficient here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Wolfgang. 
Indeed, severity groups are defined based on cut-off values (but these values vary depending on the studies: for instance, some would take 0-4, 5-7, 8-10 while other 0-5, 6-10 etc.... I guess they try to homogenise the number of patients in each group. 
Indeed, I had not thought of polyserial correlation coefficient. How should I transform it to Cohen's d later one? Shoudl I apply the same transformation as for Pearson's moment product?
  $$ d=\frac{2r}{\sqrt(1-r^2)} $$
and $$ Vd=\frac{4Vr}{(1-r^2)^3} $$
Thanks!

Comment: In fact I won't go through Cohen's d so please forget my last question. However, can I use the same Fisher Z transform as for Pearson's coefficient (arctan(r)/variance)? And if so, would it keep its normalizing properties?
Thank you!

Comment: The variance of a polyserial correlation coefficient is different than the variance of a Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient. So, if you apply Fisher's r-to-z transformation to a polyserial correlation coefficient, this won't be a variance stabilizing transformation and the variance is not $1/(n-3)$.

Comment: Dear Wolfgang,
Thank you very much. Indeed, the polyserial function in R. I will look more into this to understand how it is computed.
Thanks again! (and for all the other questions you answered and also helped me).